# angular ui grid disable or enable cell selection /focus conditionally

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a requirement that, once i fetch data and bind it to UI grid, based on the cell data, i should enable/ disable cell selection. For cell navigation? 
I am already set the cellNav option to my UI grid.
When i check the options, i see the below reference:

//Enables cell selection.
        enableCellSelection: false, // no more in v3.0.+

but it is saying no more for v3.0+, but as of now, i am using 3.0+ version only.
I am looking for a code reference with a function instead of "false" option, and my function will check the cell data and put the option..?? any references?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for allowCellFocus:

```
{
  name: 'FieldName',
  allowCellFocus: false
}
```

I am not sure what you mean by based on the cell data. If you want to enable/disable only some cells in a given column, it would have to be something that is super custom, and would probably land in the realm of very hacky.

Comment: actually, i have a requirement as like movie theatre seat selection. I have implemented using UI grid and dotnet MVC as UI as of now. But for un wanted rows / cells (seats), i would like to disable cell selection and other functionality like booking seats. can anybody let me know how to achieve this?  as of now, an user can able to click / select any cell in my grid, but i want it to be conditional based on the cell data